# Chamada URL diferente do Controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira simples de fazer com que a URL fique com nome diferente ao nome do controlador no Codeigniter.

Sabendo que o codeigniter funciona da seguinte maneira: www.meusite.com/CONTROLADOR/FUNÇÃO

Por exemplo:
Ao chamar a url www.meusite.com/Produto/Listar
Não quero que meu controlador esteja nomeado como "Produto" e sim como "ProdutoController". Porém não quer que a URL seja www.meusite.com/ProdutoController/Listar

Comment: pode fazer isso com rotas, http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Vlw.. era isso mesmo que eu queria.

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma rota em config/routes.php

```
$route['produto/listar'] = "ProdutoController/Listar";
```